# Apache: One subdomain for normal vhost, others for second vhost

Tags: apache

Forgive me if I missed something simple in spite of my efforts in trying to set up a test server, since I am still by no means an expert in configuring Apache.

## Background

I have two requirements:

1. Requests for `subdomain.domain.com` should be served from `/var/www/html/subdomain`
2. Requests for `code.domain.com` should be handled by another server *on the same system, with a different port*. Note that `code` is a fixed subdomain that should NOT be handled under the same rules as the first requirement. To put it another way, `mysite.domain.com` should be served from `/var/www/html/mysite`, and `xyz.domain.com` should be served from `/var/www/html/xyz`, BUT `code.domain.com` is handled entirely differently.

## Things Tried

To do #1, I use `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1`. For #2, I want just the `code` subdomain to use a whole different configuration that redirects traffic to another server on the same system on port 5000 using `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.

## Results

All requests are redirected via the Proxy directives according to the first `<VirtualHost>` container, even if the subdomain used is NOT `code`.

Although the `code` vhost is first in the configuration, it should not be used if the subdomain is NOT `code`, since the ServerName requested by the client is not `code.domain.com`.

## Question

*How can I reconcile these two configurations so that one particular subdomain uses one virtual host, while other subdomains use the other virtual host?*

## Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName code.domain.com
    ServerAlias code.local
    ServerAdmin foo@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/repos
    ErrorLog logs/code.domain.com
    CustomLog logs/code-access common
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
    <Directory "/var/www/repos">
       DAV On
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from all
       Order allow, deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1
    VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/html/%1/cgi-bin
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin foo@domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply let the code subdomain point to another IP?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Assuming I only have one box and NIC to work with, can that still fly? Recall that the other server is running on the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a configuration that works beautifully for me. I deleted the entire vhost configuration and replaced it with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin foo@domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%-3+
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias localhost
    CustomLog logs/domain.com-access "%V -> %u@%h (%t): %Bb %Dmu"
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

In /var/www/html/code/.htaccess, I use the P flag in mod_rewrite to proxy my traffic as needed.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:5000/$1 [L,P]
</IfModule>
```

The use of `%-3+` in `VirtualDocumentRoot` means that [I can also use more than one dot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) in my URL to access a directory with a dot in the name. For example, the test server for `anothersite.com` can be accessed with `anothersite.com.domain.com`, and the files are served from `/var/www/html/anothersite.com`.

There are two catches:

1. This only works with a wildcard CNAME record.
2. `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` requests behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

To slove your problem should not be too hard.

First exchange the both virtual hosts. The first one is every Time the default one. So if no rule matches every call is handled as a this virtual host.

Second let mod rewrite move the requests to the right directory or create a virtual host for every valid domain. The last one is much simpler and allows you to have seperate log files.

Comment: Assuming I used the second vhost as the default, would I still be able to use ProxyPass to send traffic to a different port in .htaccess?

Comment: If I don't missed something that should work. Tty it if it makes trouble I'll try to help you, when I'm on my computer. It's hard to write a server config on a mobile.